# Win10 loads more after loading

Tags: windows-10, boot

So my win10 pc started loading insanely long. At first it loads usually, then black screen shows with loading icon and it takes about 10x longer than usual boot. Then I get to see Please Wait and after that Welcome screen which also lasts forever. When PC finally boots up everything is super slow and stuttering. I have to restart PC a few times until I get normal boot time. Mbar checked - no viruses. Also HDD led is on during that black screen with loading icon. What is happening? It used to happen very rarely, but since last week almost everyday.

Comment: Failing hard disk, possibly. Try opening command window and running `chkdisk /R`   - you may have to reboot to complete the check.

Comment: Post the SMART info of the disk (using a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)).